# How can I add one image to ALL the products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images

How can I add **one image to ALL** the products in **Magento 2** ? I found an answer for Magento 1.9, but I need the code for Magento2.

Not a placeholder, I already have several images on each product and I need to add one image for each product.

Comment: Simply add placeholder image and you will get this image for all product. This is right way @KishanSavaliya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create one root file and paste below code in that file and run file in browser

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
set_time_limit(0);
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap     = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$dir = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$imagePath = $dir->getPath('media')."/yourimage.jpg"; // Your image should be on pub/media path
$imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];

if($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        if($product->getId()) {
            if(file_exists($imagePath)) {
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, $imageType, false, false);
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you, I have used your code and create a new module

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

To upload placeholder images in Magento 2

- Step 1: Login to your Magento 2 backend
- Step 2: Upload placeholder images
- Step 3: Save the configuration

**Step 1:** Login to your Magento 2 backend

On the Admin sidebar,

> Stores > Settings > Configuration

In the **panel**, under **Catalog**, choose **Catalog**.

**Step 2:** Upload placeholder images

Expand the Product Image Placeholders section.
Click on Choose File to upload the placeholder image. You can use the same or the different images for each role.

[image]

**Step 3:** Save the configuration

Clear all catch and test it.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this path in backend and add you Placeholder image in Magento 2. This placeholder image will appear on all products.

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders

[image]

Upload image here and clear your cache.

Hope this will help you!