# Magento 2 : Set default image in image uploader field in system configuration

Tags: magento2, configuration, image-upload

I want to set default image when user save configuration empty records.

> For eg : when user delete image and don't upload new image at that time, default image should be available in database/image uploader.

How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294906/how-can-i-add-one-image-to-all-the-products-in-magento-2/294912#294912

Comment: Please read question again.